# Only get message text from body using O365 python

Tags: python, html, css, office365

I coded a simple python script to get the inbox from a certain user inside my tenant. For this, I used the O365 library. Here's the code:

```
import O365
from O365 import Account, Connection,  MSGraphProtocol, Message
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, date

credentials = ('my_client_id', 'my_client_secret')


account = Account(credentials, auth_flow_type='credentials', tenant_id='mytenantid')
if account.authenticate():
   print('Authenticated!')

account.connection.refresh_token()

mailbox = account.mailbox(resource='user@company.com')
query = mailbox.new_query()
query = query.on_attribute('created_date_time').greater(datetime(2021, 7, 11))

inbox=mailbox.inbox_folder()


for message in inbox.get_messages(query=query):
    print(message.body)
```

The problem is that when I print the body message, I get the full html and css as plain text printed in my console. Is there a way to only get the contents of the message without getting any html or css? Should I code a method to get rid of the html/css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the [body_preview](https://o365.github.io/python-o365/latest/api/message.html?highlight=message#O365.message.Message.body_preview) property which returns the body preview instead of body text of current message.

Comment: Hi, thanks this really helped, I got one issue though, the body_preview method doesn't return the full preview of the messages, especially if it's a thread of messages, however, if I use the get_body_text() I do get everything but it's all as one string and unreadable, do you have a suggestion for me?

Comment: I'd suggest posting another questions separately in new threads.